# Is it possible to select an individual list item per <div> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two divs which contain five list items each. The idea is that each div title is a question, and the user can select the appropriate answer for each one.

The snippet shows the current code I have. You'll notice that you can only select one list item between both divs. I'd like the user to select one answer per div, and have that answer remain highlighted.

Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.ans').click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $('.questionlist1').children().not(this).removeClass('chosenanswer');
    $(this).toggleClass("chosenanswer");
  });
});
```

```css
.question1 {
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #424242;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 5px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 5px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: -2px 5px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.questiontitle {
  background-color: #212121;
  padding: 1.5%;
}

.questionlist1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.questionlist1 li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #616161;
  width: 16.2%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 1.8% 0 1.8% 1.5%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.questionlist1 li:nth-child(5n) {
  margin-right: 1.5%;
}

.questionlist1 li:hover,
li.chosenanswer {
  background-color: #FFCA28;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question1">
  <div class="questiontitle">This is the first div</div>
  <ul class="questionlist1">
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="question1">
  <div class="questiontitle">This is the second div</div>
  <ul class="questionlist1">
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not change your list items to contain radio buttons? Since they are designed to allow the selection of one thing only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
$(".questionlist1").children().not(this).removeClass('chosenanswer');
```

...you're getting **all** `.questionlist1` elements and then getting **all** their children, thanks to jQuery's set-based nature.

You want just the one `.questionlist1` that the clicked anwer is in, which you can get from [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(this).closest(".questionlist1").children().not(this).removeClass('chosenanswer');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.ans').click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest(".questionlist1").children().not(this).removeClass('chosenanswer');
    $(this).toggleClass("chosenanswer");
  });
});
```

```css
.question1 {
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #424242;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 5px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 5px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: -2px 5px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.questiontitle {
  background-color: #212121;
  padding: 1.5%;
}

.questionlist1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.questionlist1 li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #616161;
  width: 16.2%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 1.8% 0 1.8% 1.5%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.questionlist1 li:nth-child(5n) {
  margin-right: 1.5%;
}

.questionlist1 li:hover,
li.chosenanswer {
  background-color: #FFCA28;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question1">
  <div class="questiontitle">This is the first div</div>
  <ul class="questionlist1">
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="question1">
  <div class="questiontitle">This is the second div</div>
  <ul class="questionlist1">
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternately, since the answers are *siblings*, you can do it a bit more simply with [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('chosenanswer');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.ans').click(function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('chosenanswer');
    $(this).toggleClass("chosenanswer");
  });
});
```

```css
.question1 {
  max-width: 1000px;
  background-color: #424242;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 5px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 5px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  box-shadow: -2px 5px 9px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}

.questiontitle {
  background-color: #212121;
  padding: 1.5%;
}

.questionlist1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.questionlist1 li {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #616161;
  width: 16.2%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 1.8% 0 1.8% 1.5%;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.questionlist1 li:nth-child(5n) {
  margin-right: 1.5%;
}

.questionlist1 li:hover,
li.chosenanswer {
  background-color: #FFCA28;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question1">
  <div class="questiontitle">This is the first div</div>
  <ul class="questionlist1">
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<div class="question1">
  <div class="questiontitle">This is the second div</div>
  <ul class="questionlist1">
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ans">Item 1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```